How to use one SQLALCHEMY session in many threads?
Please tell me how I can use one session in many threads?
I tried to use something like
async def task(session: AsyncSession):
    posts = await session.scalars(select(Post))

async def main():
    async with AsyncSession() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(*[task(session) for i in range(1000)])

asyncio.run(main())

But with this approach i was getting error like: sqlalchemy.exc.IllegalStateChangeError: Method 'close()' can't be called here; method '_connection_for_bind()' is already in progress and this would cause an unexpected state change to <SessionTransactionState.CLOSED: 5> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/isce)
After that, I found out that sessions cannot be competitive, and I started creating a session for each task, something like:
async def task():
    async with AsyncSession() as session:
        posts = await session.scalars(select(Post))

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[task() for i in range(1000)])

asyncio.run(main())

And everything was fine. But exactly until the moment when the simultaneous number of tasks exceeded the maximum number of connections in my database settings. Please tell me how I can use one session for multiple threads?

Have you read the FAQ about sessions and thread safety?
